# Custom implementation of httpclient

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, httpclient, asp.net-core-webapi

I've a WebAPI that needs custom auth token to be sent in the request header.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient()
{
     client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://example.com");
     var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/adfs/oauth2/authorize);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "<token>");
    ...
    ...
    //code removed for brevity

}
```

Since lot of operations will be calling these exact lines of code. I am planning to create an implemented class of HttpClient such as below. The object of this class needs to have all the custom implementation already initialized. Can this be done?

```
public class MyHttpClient : HttpClient
{
    //how do I make sure the object of MyHttpClient will implicitly set all the desired properties (headers etc)
}


using (var client = new MyHttpClient()
{
   //client should come with all the properties initialized
}
```

Comment: add it in your constructor

Comment: can you clarify the tags used you have web api 2 and asp.net core web api, which are two separate versions of the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the default properties in the constructor of the derived class.

For example

```
public class MyHttpClient : HttpClient {

    public MyHttpClient(): base() {
        BaseAddress = new Uri("https://example.com");
        DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "<token>");
        //...
        //...
        //code removed for brevity
    }
}
```